# Merging accounts deletion

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Before merging accounts (on Stack Overflow), I got a message:

> The account xxx will be removed, and all rep and votes will be transferred to  account yyy as a result of this merge. Please click OK to confirm.

But xxx is my main account which is linked with other communities will this pertain if I click OK? Is it possible to do the reverse process delete yyy but keep xxx?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your other communities are connected to the *network* account, not each individual profile. Your network accounts also get merged in the process, so any duplicate communities are all merged together, resulting in a single profile for each community connected to a single network account.

It is not possible to do the reverse. Merges always go into the lower user ID.